# Simple Regexp Pattern matching with escape characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Hopefully a simple one!

I've been trying to get this to work for several hours now but am having no luck, as I'm fairly new to regexp I may be missing something very obvious here and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  The pattern I want to match is as follows: -

At least 1 or more numbers + "##" + at least 1 or more numbers + "##" + at least 1 or more numbers

so a few examples of valid combinations would be: -
1##2##3
123#123#123
0##0##0

A few invalid combinations would be
a##b##c
1## ##1

I've got the following regexp like so: -

```
[\d+]/#/#[\d+]/#/#[\d+]
```

And am using it like so (note the double slashes as its inside a string): -

```
var patt = new RegExp("[\\d+]/#/#[\\d+]/#/#[\\d+]");
if(newFieldValue!=patt){newFieldValue=="no match"}
```

I also tried these but still nothing: -

```
if(!patt.text(newFieldValue)){newFieldValue==""}
if(patt.text(newFieldValue)){}else{newFieldValue==""}
```

But nothing I try is matching, where am I going wrong here?

Any pointers gratefully received, cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I can't see any reason to use the `RegExp` constructor over a RegExp literal for your case. (The former is used primarily where the pattern needs to by dynamic, i.e. is contributed to by variables.)

2) You don't need a character class if there's only one type of character in it (so `\d+` not `[\d+]`

3) You are not actually checking the pattern against the input. You don't apply RegEx by creating an instance of it and using `==`; you need to use `test()` or `match()` to see if a match is made (the former if you want to check only, not capture)

4) You have `==` where you mean to assign (`=`)

```
if (!/\d+##\d+##\d+/.test(newFieldValue)) newFieldValue = "no match";
```

Comment: Thanks for this, you've pointed out a few issues I've had and explained why hence my vote.  Plus your method takes up less lines than mine so is much nicer!  Even ignoring the missing ")" :)

Answer (score 2):

You put `+` inside the brackets, so you're matching a single character that's either a digit or `+`, not a sequence of digits. I also don't understand why you have `/` before each `#`, your description doesn't mention anything about this character.
Use:

```
var patt = /\d+##\d+##\d+/;
```

Comment: the "/" was because I thought I needed to escape the # (thought it was a special character, turns out its not! :)

Comment: But escape is backslash, not slash.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the test method of the pat regex

```
if (!patt.test(newFieldValue)){ newFieldValue=="no match"; }
```

once you have a valid regular expression.

Comment: It doesn't matter what method he uses if the regexp is totally wrong.

Comment: As Barmar noted, you should first correct the regular expression. Once it is valid, you should use it with the test method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex :

```
^(?:\d+##){2}\d+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Demo:** http://regex101.com/r/mE8aG7

With the following regex

> [\d+]/#/#[\d+]/#/#[\d+]

You would only match things like:

- `+/#/#5/#/#+`
- `+/#/#+/#/#+`
- `0/#/#0/#/#0`

because the regex engine sees it like on the schema below:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: wow this is a great summary, thanks for the detail, sorry but I already picked an answer but if I could pick more I'd also pick yours for the awesome diagrams and explanations!  Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`((-\s)?\d+##)+\d+`

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if this one works or not as am not familiar with regexp enough to be able to decipher this, can you break it down a bit?